# replacing first few digits with #

Tags: php

I want to hide the first 6 digits of social security
I have them like 123-456-7890

I want to show ###-###-7890

how can I do that
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ssn = '123-456-7890';    
$ssn = '###-###-'.substr ($ssn , 8);
```

Comment: or `'###-###'.substr($ssn,7)`. the dash will be there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the substr method to get the rightmost 4 characters from the SSN using a negative length:

```
$ssn = '111-222-4567';
$ssn_obscured = '###-###-' . substr($ssn, -4);
```

See http://us.php.net/substr for more information on the method.