# Masking a social security number

Tags: php

I have a Social Security number showing up like this:

`1234567890`

I want to show it like this:

`###-##-7890`

So, basically, masking the first five digits and entering hyphens.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to a globalized world, where "SS Number" can mean *so* many different things depending which country you're in. :)

Comment: Is the number already validated?

Comment: How is that different to this questions of yours: [replacing first few digits with #](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159987/replacing-first-few-digits-with)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$number = '###-##-'.substr($ssn, -4);`

just make the starting part a string and concat that with the last 4 digits. Either that or do it in the query itself like `SELECT CONCAT('###-##-', RIGHT(ssn, 4)) FROM customer...`

Answer (score 3):

This will take the last 4 numbers and mask the rest:

```
$number = "1234567890";
$number = "###-##-" . substr($number, -4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ssno = substr_replace($ssno, '#####-', 0, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = "1234567890";
$number = "###-##-".$number[7].$number[8].$number[9].$number[10];
```